# Pyramid Response Showing in Console Log, Not on Page

Tags: python, pyramid

I'm trying to make my first Pyramid app, and I think I'm having a basic hang up with regard to Responses.

I have a list of tuples and I want to print them to a web page, but instead the web page is blank and the list appears in the Terminal window instead. The entire app:

```
from wsgiref.simple_server import make_server
from pyramid.config import Configurator
from pyramid.response import Response
from photoCollect import photoCollect

def printPhotos(request):
  photoTable = photoCollect()
  return Response(photoTable)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    config = Configurator()
    config.add_route('productlist','/productlist')
    config.add_view(printPhotos, route_name='productlist')
    app = config.make_wsgi_app()
    server = make_server('0.0.0.0', 8080, app)
    server.serve_forever()
```

and `photoCollect` is defined as:

```
import urllib
import pandas as pd

def photoCollect():
  # pull photo directory
  mypath = "http://gwynniebee.com/photos"
  mylines = urllib.urlopen(mypath).readlines()

  # strip down web page to retain just photo names
  photonames = []
  for item in mylines:
    if ".jpg" in item:
      k = item.replace('<',' ')
      splitItem = k.split(" ")
      for x in splitItem:
        if "=" not in x and ".jpg" in x:
          photonames.append(x)

  photoFrame = pd.DataFrame(photonames, columns=['name'])

  # break photo names into vendor-color-order
  photoFrame['name2'] = photoFrame['name'].apply(lambda x: x.replace('.jpg',''))
  s = photoFrame['name2'].apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x.split('-')))

  # concat vendor-color into style
  s['style'] = s[0] + "-" + s[1]
  s['order'] = s[2]
  photoFrame = photoFrame.join(s)

  # find first photo for each style and recreate photo name
  styleMin = photoFrame.groupby('style')['order'].min()
  photoName = pd.DataFrame(styleMin)
  photoName = photoName.reset_index()
  photoName['name'] = photoName['style'] + "-" + photoName['order']+".jpg"

  # generate list to send to web
  webList = pd.DataFrame("http://gwynniebee.com/photos/"+ photoName['name'])
  webList['style'] = photoName['style']

  webList = webList.set_index('name')
  photoList = list(webList.itertuples()) 

  print photoList
```

How do I make the list display on the web page instead? I am confused as to why the Response is showing in the log rather than on the page.

Comment: And what does `photoCollect` do?

Comment: it returns a list of tuples with the names of some photos. [This](https://github.com/quaintm/beeProjects/blob/master/productList/photoCollect.py) is the code for photoCollect

Comment: Right, and the error is in *that* method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `photoCollect()` method **prints** the output:

```
print photoList
```

Printing writes data to `sys.stdout`, which is redirected to the log when running a WSGI server.

You want to *return* `photoList` instead:

```
return photoList
```

Without a `return` statement, the default return value is `None`, and `Response(None)` results in an empty page.

With the `return` the caller of the `photoCollect()` function actually receives that list.

Comment: When I change `print` to `return`, I get the following error: "AssertionError: write() argument must be string"

Comment: @quaintm: then turn that list into a string first.